# How can I create a numpy array with shape (0, 2)?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to understand how a np.array can be created with shape(0,2).

Is this even possible?

So

```
np.array([]).shape
#output (0,)

np.array([[],[]]).shape
#output (2, 0)
```

can I get (0, 2) ?

(without using .T)

Comment: `np.array([[],[]]).T.shape`?

Comment: @Divakar without Transposing

Comment: `np.array([[],[]]).swapaxes(0,1)`?

Comment: The problem with nested lists is that the outer list will necessarily contain lists, and won't have a 0 size.  Shape (0,2) means 0 'rows', 2 'columns'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a function such as `np.zeros`. No need to worry about the value it generates since there are no values in a 0 x 2 array:

```
arr = np.zeros((0, 2))
arr.shape

(0, 2)
```

Comment: Note that the display of `arr` `array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=float64)` does not use any nested brackets.  It has an explicit `shape` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by `np.empty((0,2))` or `np.zeros((0,2))`.

`np.empty()`, unlike `np.zeros()`, does not set the array values to zero and it is slightly faster.

**Extra information:**
In your code `np.array([]).shape` outputs a rank-1 array which is equal to its transpose.